# Synchronizing actual version of Mercurial repository for multiple workplaces

Tags: repository, mercurial

I have three different Linux-based working places, each with a different computer. I need to have a repository synchronized to keep coding on the latest version each time I move from a workplace to another. You can always commit and push to, say, bitbucket and then pull from another computer, but this is not the purpose of a commit.

Other similar posts did not help, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378106/synchronizing-a-collection-of-mercurial-repositories.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Either keep working on the same machine (e.g. via SSH) or use a network mount (e.g. NFS, CIFS, SSHFS) and store the repository in a single location.

Comment: That's problematic: the computers are laptops (not really for 24x7), and they're in rather different places (a public institution -accessible- and home -dynamic IP). I would rather prefer to automatically synchronize with cron and leave a copy wherever I am.

Comment: Then maybe [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) or [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) might be of interest.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mercurial's workflow. Why isn't committing and pushing an acceptable solution? It's what I do with git, and it's a pretty basic use of DVCS.

Comment: You typically commit when there's some body of work finished. With my current agenda I could complete a new line of code and head somewhere else...

Comment: You can|have to commit at any time really, as you want|it's needed. And you **must** to have Central Repo in your case - it's just will have "dirty" history in worst case (commit --amend)